# How to grep/sed as a safe fallback

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, pipe

I am looking for a way to nest grep actions so if the first grep does not match, the following is used over input, but in case some grep exits successfully the the chain is interrupted

I tried with `echo $'b\nc\nd' | { grep 'a' || grep 'b' || grep 'c' || grep 'd'; }`
expecting it to fail the first grep, and therefore succeed and finish the second, so the global output would be 'b'.

Then I thought that maybe there's an easier way if I manage to flag grep so it outputs the input as it is in case it fails to match anything. Then this would be as easy as

`echo $'b\nc\nd' | grep --if-error-print-input 'a' | grep --if-error-print-input 'b' | grep --if-error-print-input 'c' | grep --if-error-print-input 'd'`

### example input and output

```
echo $'Foo\nBar' | grep -e 'Bar' -e 'Foo' | head -n 1
Foo
```

where I expect `Bar` because it has precedence

Comment: The first `grep` would read the complete output of `echo`, leaving no data for the later `grep` runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be done with `awk` only but not with `sed` or a single `grep`.

```
$ cat regexes 
c
b
a
```

The first matching line must be stored for each pattern (except for those with lower precedence than the highest-ranking match):

```
echo $'b\nc\nd' |
    awk 'BEGIN { while (getline regex <"regexes") regexes[i++]=regex; num=i; limit=i; };'\
      '{ for(i=0;i<limit;i++) { if($0~regexes[i]) { regexmatch[i]=$0; limit=i; if (i==0) { exit; } else break; }; }; };'\
      'END { for(i=0;i<num;i++) if (regexmatch[i]!="") { print regexmatch[i]; exit; }; }'
c
```

Comment: The first of your answers is amazingly clever , did not think of. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Mmh after few usage, for some reason the first idea is throwing inconsistent results when input changes. Looks like the order of tests is not guaranteed

Comment: @Whimusical Please explain in detail (with the different inputs) what you mean. No matter what the test order is, the result should always be the same. You get the first line which matches one of the tests.

Comment: Right now in my shell ```echo $'Foo\nBar'  | grep -e 'Bar' -e 'Foo' | head -n 1```

Result: Foo, where I expect 'Bar' because it has precedence

Comment: @Whimusical It turns out that both Stephen and me have misunderstood what you want. This shows once more how important it is to have example input and output in the question (I added them). I completely changed my answer. Now it should work as you want.

Comment: I ended up using ```echo "$(for element in "${ELEMENTS[@]}"; do echo $'Foo\nBar' |  grep -e "$element"; done)" | head -n 1``` but your answer is the most completed